# Sorting an Array of objects given an ordered list of ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I have a collection of objects `@users`, each having its `id` attribute.

```
@users = [#<User id:1>, #<User id:2>]
```

I also have an ordered Array of `ids`.

```
ids = [2,1]
```

¿Is there a magical way to sort the collection using that list of ids? Without making another call to the database, if possible.

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this. First, build up a reverse mapping from id -> user.

```
ids_users = {}

@users.each {|user| ids_users[user.id] = user}
```

Then, use the ids order

```
ids.collect{ |id| ids_users[id] }
```

Comment: Alternative way to construct the hash: `id_users = Hash[ @users.map { |u| [u.id, u] } ]`

Answer (score 21):

In fact you don't need to sort, build an intermediate indexed hash, it's O(n):

```
users_by_id = Hash[@users.map { |u| [u.id, u] }]
users_by_id.values_at(*ids)
```

If you still wanted to try a sort approach, the [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) would be adequate:

```
@users.sort_by { |u| ids.index(u.id) }
```

However, using `index` within a loop is a red flag: O(n^2) time. We can build an intermediate hash to go back to O(n*log n):

```
indexes = Hash[ids.each_with_index.to_a]
@users.sort_by { |u| indexes[u.id] }
```

Comment: Awesome one-liner solution. Thanks for the link to Schwartzian transform.

Comment: How about the situation when some items may repeat ? For example the list of last viewed files.

Comment: @Artur79: Then you probably need `Enumerable#group_by`

Answer (score 1):

You *certainly* don't need to go to the DB since you already have the `User` objects, although since the users are in an array, you'd probably want to create a temporary map of id => `User` to get the end result.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the id of each user by calling user.id, you could sort the array like this:

```
@users.sort!{|a,b| a.id <=> b.id }
```

If you only have the ids in a separate array from the objects you could do the following:
Zip the two arrays together, sort the resulting array on the ids, then collect the sorted users from the result.

```
users_ids = @users.zip(ids) # creates an array of smaller arrays each holding [user, id]
users_ids.sort!{|a,b| a[1] <=> b[1]} # sorts on the id in each sub-array
sorted_users = users_ids.collect{|item| item[0]} #grabs the users, leaving the ids behind
```

Take a glance at this: http://ariejan.net/2007/01/28/ruby-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-an-attribute