# How do I use the sorted unique ids in redis to display users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I am trying to create a highscore board for my Users. I am using redis-objects gem for this task.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Redis::Objects
  sorted_set :leaderboard, global: true
  after_update :update_leaderboard

    def update_leaderboard
      self.class.leaderboard[id] = score
    end
end
```

With this method, I got the user ids and sorted by their score everytime I update the scores.

```
User.leaderboard.revrange(0,2) #["3", "1", "2"]
```

My question:

How can I make use of the arrays of sorted ids, and display my users based on the order? Lets say I want to sort my users in index page.

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def index
  @users = User.all
  end
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: Props for using Redis, this is how it should be used!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def index
    ids = User.leaderboard.revrange(0,2)
    @users = User.all.sort_by { |u| ids.index(u.id) }
  end
end
```

For more information [sorting-an-array-of-objects-given-an-ordered-list-of-ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788456/sorting-an-array-of-objects-given-an-ordered-list-of-ids)

Comment: That gives you all User objects, not just the ones on the leaderboard excerpt.

Answer (score 0):

The `find` method will take an array, but sorting is a problem... if you don't mind sorting at the app level...

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def index
    arr = User.leaderboard.revrange(0,2)
    @users = User.find(arr).sort_by{|user| arr.index user.id}
  end
end
```

Someone may have a better solution...